# Django deployed project not running subprocess shell command

Tags: python, django, shell, subprocess, gunicorn

I have a django 1.9 project deployed using gunicorn with a view contains a line

> subprocess.call(["xvfb-run ./stored/all_crawlers.sh "+outputfile+" " + url], shell=True, cwd= path_to_sh_file)

which runs fine with ./manage.py runserver 
but fails on deployment and (deployed with gunicorn and wsgi).

Any Suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that user permission are ok?

Comment: Could be a permission issue. Manage.py runs with your own user, deployment with www-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) User who runs gunicorn has no permissions to run .sh files

2) Your .sh file has no rights to be runned

3) Try to user full path to the file

Also, which error do you get when trying to run it on the production?